# How do I use executemany to write the first values in each Key to a database

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sqlite, executemany

I am new to Python and am trying to use a for loop to add the first and subsequent values, sequentially from a list within a dictionary to a database by using the cursor.executemany() function.

here is my code,

```
dict = {'yo': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'meh':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'blah':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}

conn = sqlite3.connect('tester.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE Numbers (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    yo  INTEGER,
    meh INTEGER,
    blah    INTEGER
);

''')

for key,val in dict.items():
    i = 0

    cur.executemany('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Number_game (yo,meh,blah)
    VALUES (?,?,?)''', (val(i))
    i = i+1                     
    conn.commit()
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the i = i+1 iteration. I am trying to add all the 1's to the first row, then the 2's and so on. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? it feels like a glaring mistake im unable to pick up.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

executemany wants a list of tuples each one containing one row, that is, one element from yo, one from meh, and one from blah. That is not what `.items()` provide, since it will provide a key and the values associated with that key on each iteration.

Luckly the `zip()` function does exactly what you need:

```
cur.executemany('...insert...', zip(my_dict['yo'], my_dict['meh'], my_dict['blah']))
```